# How to Update the Fragment View in android in every 30 seconds?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to build an Friend Tracking app.Now I am using a Fragment and in the `onCreateView` in every 30 seconds i will update the tracker i.e i will take the position of my friend from database and accordingly update it in the map.I have tried like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracking_friend, null, false);

    online = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvOnline);
    lastseen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLastSeen);
    tv_last_seen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.reltrack);

    mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.tracking_map);
    map = mapFrag.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
    rel.startAnimation(animation);


    data = getArguments();
    mail = data.getString("mail");

   /* while (true) {
        checkForPosition(mail);
        return v;
    }*/
   while(true) {
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               checkForPosition(mail);
               Log.i("tracking","i am in thread");

           }



       }).start();
       return v;

   }

}
```

The problem is that it is not calling the `checkForPosition()` method after one time.But i need to call the `checkForPosition()` method to update the tracker in the map.Is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 1):

Android will kill any process that uses while(true) or recursive threads/tasks which is why your code executes only once. It may even kill timers that never stop... idk. I'd use an Intent Service that starts in the foreground. This is the little icon in your notifications like when you start Pandora. It's Android's best way of executing long running processes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimerTask to do this:

```
TimerTask urTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that you put your logic into 
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30000); //execute in every 30 secs
```

Comment: Ditch the `TimerTask` and just use the `Handler`'s `postDelayed(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a friend tracker to !

If you are using google maps you can do it very easy by just clearing it and drawing the markers again every 30 seconds with the new lat,long coordinates from your database.

```
mMap.clear();    
customarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(title).snippet(snippet).icon(iconBitmap));
```